# Magento How to check if the shopping cart is empty or not?

Tags: php, magento, cart

I am trying to check if the shopping cart is empty or not.
I am trying to do this from a static block and from a phtml file.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Well i tried $this->getOrders(); But of course then i would have to extend from History.php. But in the toplinks i want to display 'Shoppingbag' when it's empty. and when it is not empty: 'Shopping bag(3) | Order now'. (if there are three items in the shopping bag.)

Well i don't think my code would be of any help here. :P

Comment: Go to the Question you have asked and mark your Questions as solved if they are correct.

Comment: Ah thanks for the tip, i found it :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I was able to find the total count of items in the shopping cart using the following code:

```
$totalItemsInCart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
```

If it does not work, let me know.

Comment: Ah thanks this did the trick for me :)
I would upvote you but my reputation is too low..

Comment: How can i find if cart has selected category of products? I have category id's how can i check if cart has selected categories of products? @Mukesh

Answer (score 4):

You can try this.

```
$cart_qty = (int) Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsQty();

if($cart_qty) {
    // Not empty.
} else {
    // Empty.
}
```

Comment: Why we put (int)  may i know the reason? @Cj Belo thanks

Comment: To force the return data to be an integer. If the method returned "1" then it will be converted to 1.

Comment: Thank you and one more if not using INT may i know what is the error shown? @Cj Belo

Comment: If you're not gonna put (int) it's still okay. It will still return a data.

Answer (score 3):

I think this could help:

http://blog.decryptweb.com/empty-cart-magento/

You can try something like this:

```
$checkout_cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$items = $checkout_cart->getItems();
```

Comment: Ah i tried your code but for some reason it kept giving me an empty array.